# Which Email Server supports IDN hosting ? Please suggest IDN compatible IMAP email clientss

Tags: email, server, email-server

My organisation is looking to host Gujarati language domain name (IDN) for email addresses. Could anyone suggest me email softaware. Surprisingly Google Apps, Office365 do not host these IDNs as of now. Even cloud solution is also fine. Just 20 ids required.